# How to specify a login_hint parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api-ruby-client

I read the `Google Oauth2` documentation and it seems that I can send a `login_hint` parameter as part of the authorization request, similar to specifying `access_type`.

I am using an offline `access_type` for a web server application (Rails application).

I tried setting the parameter on the Client's authorization object as well as passing it as an option when initializing the client but it never auto-fills the login box nor is sent as a query parameter.

All I'm trying to do is, if the user is logged in to Gmail already with a different account then they should be prompted to login / select a different account (which is specified in the login_hint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by setting the `login_hint` parameter using the `additional_parameters` hash which is available on `Signet::OAuth2::Client`.

Basically, doing the following:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(application_name: 'test application', application_version: '0.0.1')
client.authorization.additional_parameters[:login_hint] = 'some_address@gmail.com'
```

If you get an error about `additional_parameters` not being defined then make sure you are using a recent version of the `signet` gem or use the latest from the master branch.